# reading 512 bytes at a time from a file and checking what's inside?

Tags: c

I have a large file that contains a lot of jpegs inside. All jpegs need to be extracted one by one. Here are my first steps at  approaching this problem:

1) define "block" variable and allocate 512 bytes of storage to it

2) open file that contains all jpegs and loop through it until eof

3) grab first block (512 bytes) and see what's inside

Currently my code doesn't compile. Here are my errors:

```
 recover.c:27:19: error: implicitly declaring C library function
 'malloc' with type 'void *(unsigned int)' [-Werror]
     char* block = malloc(BYTE * 512);
                   ^ recover.c:27:19: note: please include the header <stdlib.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'malloc'
 recover.c:27:26: error: unexpected type name 'BYTE': expected
 expression
     char* block = malloc(BYTE * 512);
                          ^ recover.c:45:18: error: conversion specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'char *'
 [-Werror,-Wformat]
         printf("%c", block);
                 ~^   ~~~~~
                 %s
```

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

//SOI - 0xFF 0xD8
//EOI - 0xFF 0xD9
//APPn - 0xFF 0xEn    
int main(void)
{
    //FAT - 512 bytes per block
    char* block = malloc(BYTE * 512);

    //open file containing pictures
    FILE* fh = fopen("card.raw", "rd");

    //make sure the file opened without errors
    if (fh == NULL)
    {
        printf("something went wrong and file could not be opened");
        return 1;
    }

    while (!feof(fh))
    {
        setbuf(fh, block);
        printf("%c", block);
    }

    fclose(fh);
return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't char* block = malloc(BYTE * 512); allocating 512 bytes, but throws an error instead?
Also, since I can't even compile this piece yet, am I reading 512 bytes correctly? If not, how can I go about accomplishing this?

Thanks.

Comment: The first thing you do is include stdlib.h so there is a proper prototype for malloc() in scope.   Then, check the return value from malloc() to make sure it succeeds.  That should get you started on the proper path at least.

Comment: The error message tells you the exact problem; you need to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: There's no need to use `malloc()` at all in this code. Just declare `char block[512]`;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

To get the definition of `malloc()`.

```
char* block = malloc(BYTE * 512);
```

Should be (because `malloc` takes the argument in terms of bytes already; `sizeof(BYTE)` would return `1`):

```
char* block = malloc(512);
```

And:

```
printf("%c", block);
```

Should be:

```
printf("%s", block);
```

And like EJP said in a comment, while this isn't an error, there isn't a real need for dynamically allocating the `buffer` with `malloc()`. You already know you will need 512 bytes for what you're doing, so you can replace that line with:

```
char block[512];
```

I take it you're using clang as your compiler, which as you can see is really helpful with it's error messages, it basically tells you how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you! No idea how I missed what compiler told me.